# Is it possible to modify the contents of a file from ExtractTextPlugin before the file is written?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack

I want to pull some CSS files being made from the `less-loader` into external files using `ExtractTextPlugin`, but I want to make two files, one base file, and one with some modifications to the CSS.

Is there a way to do something like this, but with existing plugins?

```
new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].a.css'),
new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].b.css', { transform: someFunc }),
```

I've tried to use `CopyWebpackPlugin` to do this, but file a isn't written to disk before `CopyWebpackPlugin` runs and I would prefer not to do this operation after the build is complete using something like `FileManagerPlugin`.

Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: What exactly do you want to transform in the css file?

Comment: Just rewriting some of the properties, nothing major. I just need two separate files based on a single LESS file.

Comment: `nothing major` all clear. good luck ;)

Comment: I can get the two files, just can't transform  one before it's written to disk. Any ideas?

Comment: wouldnt it be easier to use post-css? it was made specifically for this, no?

Comment: @DanielLizik Yes, I am more interested in knowing if this is possible. I have messed with Webpack some, but still learning. It seems like there would be a plugin to just pull in something from the bundle and run it through a function and write that to a file. I am using post-css in the loaders for autoprefixing, but I want to do some custom rtl transformations after the fact.

Comment: @jazzy i would throw together a custom webpack plugin that calls postcss api automatically. you can write your second css file with mods inside the context of the webpack plugin.

Comment: @DanielLizik This is what I ended up doing the next day. If you make this a fleshed-out answer I will accept it